# Thermostat controller switch?

Tags: hvac

Would two thermostats be possible if a master control switch was in place. For example I leave one end  of the house, throw the control switch, and set the  thermostat at the other end of the house. (Living room is freezing while bedroom is warm.)

Comment: There are smart thermostats (Like the Ecobee) that have motion detection and remote sensors that do this automatically.  That said, you could use simple switches to do it.  Do you just want a switch to turn each thermostat on or off?  Is it ok if both thermostats are "on" at the same time?

Comment: @Jerry_Contrary I read it as "thermostat is in the living room, so I want to turn it off when I leave because the bedroom is already warm".  Perhaps Mike could clarify tho.

Comment: @jphi1618 I guess more clarification is needed.

Comment: This is an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) but you've made clear what both the X and Y are, so it should be answerable.

Comment: Have you tried having your ductwork balanced properly?

Comment: JPhi - Yes a switch to  turn each on/off.   Jerry - the thermostat is in a hallway between the two ends of the house.  ThreePhaseEel - Never heardof ductwork balancing. Is that a common thing?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible and very easy with simple thermostats. For example twp non powered thermostats could be controlled in such a way with a 3 way switch. R from the furnace goes to the common terminal and the switched terminals go to the corresponding are terminal on each thermostat.